# How to get MuPAD to do some integrals for me (involving heaviside and dirac functions)?

Tags: convolution, symbolic-math, mupad

My goal is to compute the n-fold self-convolution of a function rho(eta) where eta > 0, using MuPAD. (The background are energy densities of systems composed of many identical subsystems.)  I tried to start with a simple case, but I'm already getting stuck there:

I define rho(eta) to be constantly 1 for eta > 0, so it is a Heaviside function:

```
rho := eta -> heaviside(eta)
```

and I implement the 2-fold self-convolution using a double integral and a Dirac delta function:

```
int(int(rho(etaA) * rho(etaB) * dirac(etaA + etaB - energy), etaB = 0..infinity), etaA=0..infinity)
```

with the result

[image]

so MuPAD wasn't even able to simplify the integral over a delta function and obtain a normal convolution expression; no idea what's going on with the limit here.

If I just directly enter the normal convolution expression of the function with itself

```
int(rho(etaA) *  rho(energy - etaA), etaA = 0..infinity)
```

I get

[image]

again with a limit (which could be simplified to 0, or couldn't it?). The second term comes actually close to the correct answer, the `heaviside` just accounts for the possibility that `energy` may be negative. Ok, so I tell MuPAD that `energy` is positive:

```
int(rho(etaA) *  rho(energy - etaA), etaA = 0..infinity) assuming energy > 0
```

and now MuPAD just gives me back the original unchanged integral:

[image]

Well, maybe using `heaviside` is the problem, and it is not strictly necessary anyway since I implement the constraint to eta > 0 through the integration limits. So I redefine

```
rho := eta -> 1
```

and use the formula with the delta function, plus the information that `energy` is positive:

```
int(int(rho(etaA) * rho(etaB) * dirac(etaA + etaB - energy), etaB = 0..infinity), etaA=0..infinity) assuming energy > 0
```

Guess what? Now MuPAD *returns* a heaviside by itself:

[image]

which is correct – but why doesn't it evaluate this integral? It's not that hard, is it?

So please anyone tell me: Why is all this happening? And how can I make it work?

Comment: Looks like the n-fold convolution of a step function is a piecewise polynomial of degree n. I think we could work it out by hand if that was important, but I am guessing you are really interested in some other functions. What is the function that you really want to compute the n-fold convolution of, if it is not a step function?

Comment: @RobertDodier, yes, I can compute this convolution myself by hand, but what I want is to be able to easily play with different functions rho(eta). So this question is really not about this particular self-convolution (for that I would have asked on math.SE), or about the self-convolution of a small set of given functions, but about forcing MuPAD to do this for me in general, so I can focus on other things than the technicalities of integration.

Comment: I seldomly need computer algebra, and every time I try and use it I end up in frustration. I was hoping here to get some pointers from some more experienced users. – Thinking about it, maybe I should rename my question...